# Evitar enviar formulario si DatePicker esta vacio

Tags: php, jquery, html, formularios

Hola: Tengo un formulario con varios checkbox los cuales invoco con un script para mostrar un calendario datepicker y un horario con timepicker al ser seleccionada una checkbox y me de opcion para seleccionar hora y fecha. El detalle es que si yo no selecciono fecha y hora con date y time picker el formulario se pasa sin datos al no haber seleccionado ninguna hora y ninguna fecha. Les anexo un tramo del codigo. ¿Como puedo validar para que me indique que debo llenar o seleccionar forzosamente las dos opciones de fecha y hora? OJO no deseo seleccionar datetimepicker. Gracias.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
    <style>
    p.ex1 {
      padding: 2cm;
    }
    p.ex2 {
      padding: 0.5cm 3cm;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showContent()
    {
      element = document.getElementById("content");
      check = document.getElementById("pase_de_entrada");
      if (check.checked)
      {
        element.style.display='block';
      }
      else
      {
        element.style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("date").value = "";
        document.getElementById("time").value = "";
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>

<body>
<p class="ex1">Pruebas</p>
<p class="ex2"></p>
<form role="form" class="login-form" action="verificar.php" method="POST" >
  <fieldset class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2">Tipo de Pase</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" id="pase_de_entrada" type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Pase de entrada" onchange="javascript:showContent()" /> Pase de Entrada </label></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length === 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('DEBES SELECCIONAR EL TIPO DE PASE(S)');
      }
    });
    </script>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="form-inline">
    <div id="content" style="display: none;">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-form-label" for="fecha_justificar">Fecha a Justificar Entrada</label>
        <div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control" id="date" name="date[]" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text" value=""/></div>
        <link data-semver="0.0.6" rel="stylesheet" href="http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.css" />
        <!-- taking out AO theme <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-theme.css" /> -->
        <script  data-semver="0.0.6" src="http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var date_input=$('input[name="date[]"]');
          var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
          var options={
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
          };
          date_input.datepicker(options);
        })
        </script>
        <!--Zona del Hora -->
        <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-form-label" for="hora_justificar">Hora a Justificar</label>
        <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-placement="left" data-align="top" data-autoclose="true" >
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="time[]" id="time" value="">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span></div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="jquerys/clockpicker-gh-pages/src/clockpicker.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquerys/clockpicker-gh-pages/src/clockpicker.css"/>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          $('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
          var time_input=$('input[name="time[]"]');
          </script>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn" id="btn-formulario" name="enviar" value="enviar" >Enviar Solicitud a RH</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php        
 foreach ($_POST['date'] as $key1 => $value1)
 $selected1 .= $value1.'    ';
 
 foreach ($_POST['time'] as $key1 => $value1)
 $selected2 .= $value1.'   ';
 
 echo 'FECHA SELECCIONADA '.$selected1.'';
 echo '<br>';
 echo 'HORA SELECCIONADA '.$selected2.'';

?>
```

[image: Formulario]
[image: Resultado]

Comment: con required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer algo así te valdría, donde compruebas si se ha checkeado el tipo de pase:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
  if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length === 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('DEBES SELECCIONAR EL TIPO DE PASE(S)');
  }
  if($('#time').val() === '' || $('#date').val() === ''){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('DEBES SELECCIONAR HORA Y FECHA');
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias con esto he validado ambos campos de date y time picker. Saludos y de nuevo gracias por tu valiosa ayuda.